# Troubles reading values of a struct attributes, which are of int* type

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am practicing for a C++ exam. Even in copies of previous exams there are instances where this works (although we're writing the code on paper, at least for now).

This is one of the structures (the simplest one among them all):

```
struct Date{
    int* _d, *_m, *_y;
    void Create(int d, int m, int y)
    {
        _d = new int;
        _m = new int;
        _y = new int;

        *_d = d;
        *_m = m;
        *_y = y;
    }
}
```

Now, in `main()` function, if I do this:

```
Date date;
Date* pDate = new Date;

date.Create(1,1,2001);
pDate->Create(2,2,2002);

cout << "The month: " << *date._m << endl;
cout << "The month: " << *date->_m << endl;
```

the console will crash or similar - it won't print out the month value.

I also tried this:
    cout << "The month: " << *(date._m) << endl;
    cout << "The month: " << *(date->_m) << endl;

but to no avail.

Anyone willing to help? Thank you!

EDIT: Here's the complete code: http://pastebin.com/DMWx2Hk5

EDIT: It turned out that my member function name (Create) got corrupted or something like that, and that alone was the culprit for console crashes. I changed it and it started to work.

Comment: You have absolutely no need to use pointers in any of this.

Comment: I agree, but that's how the students got that problem on paper. I also thought I should remove these pointer attributes and make them plain integers but.. I guess I should first find a way for this to work as it is.

Comment: And if you *do* need to work with pointers, it is essential to initialize them! Otherwise you don't know if they point to allocated memory or not.

Comment: @crashmstr I just added initialization of `pDate` (the one which is made pointer)

Comment: It turned out that my member function name (Create) got corrupted or something like that, and that alone was the culprit for console crashes. I changed it and it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have not allocated any memory to `pDate`, you need `Date* pDate = new Date()` - The pointers `_d` `_m` and `_y` have to live somewhere, in the case of `date` they're taking up `3*sizeof(int*)` bytes on the stack, but for the case of your pointer, those 3 points don't live anywhere yet. so you need to allocate memory on the heap for them using `new`

Comment: Actually, I did, I just didn't replicate the whole thing here. Please find the whole problem, I will paste the link soon.

Comment: Please replicate the problem using a short example. The code you've put up there doesn't work for that reason

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code above, other than that on the last line you meant `*pDate->_m` not `*date->_m`

Comment: I just removed everything from the ˙main()˙ leaving out the possibility that something else is interfering. It still doesn't work. This really puzzles me

Comment: It turned out that my member function name (Create) got corrupted or something like that, and that alone was the culprit for console crashes. I changed it and it started to work.